# Why did Ghost not participate in the war?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S06 E09 why did Ghost (Jon Snow's direwolf) not appear in the war? It might have helped a lot for Jon. Also Ramsay was attacked by hounds, so why not Ghost?

Comment: I've editted that other question's title so that hopefully people wondering the same thing can actually find it now!

Comment: Well, Ramsay wasn't *attacked* by hounds. He was *eaten* by *his own* hounds. Because he was keeping them hungry so they'd eat people. Plus the hounds did just fine, I don't think they really needed Ghost's help.